# HTML/Javascript use src string in onclick without retyping?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, image, src

I want to use the same string in my img "src" in my "onclick" as a parameter to a function. What's the easiest way to do this? It works fine if I type it out both times but it doesn't look nice.

Here is an example so you can see what I mean...

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" onclick="doStuff('/images/image1.jpg')"/>
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to have the src in the onclick too that doesn't require me to write it out again? So I can use a general onclick for each image that needs to be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to pass the object itself into the function. So:

`<img src="/images/image1.jpg" onclick="doStuff(this.src)">`

Will do what you want, I believe.

Comment: I have chosen this as the correct answer because although they are all correct, this one is the most personal and Jamie took the time to write complete sentences. I do Like efficiency but I am also a human being. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" onclick="doStuff(this.src)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
doStuff(this.src);
```

Comment: Thank you. These answers are all correct, how do I choose the one to vote up and which to accept as the answer?